# returning value of for loop in python from one function to another

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, module

I want to achieve this

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

but using different functions, by putting values of for-loop to variable named `valuee` and then as an argument to `clamp` function then printing it. Why am I getting just 1? and not from 1->9?

```
def clamp(valuee):
         print(valuee)

def value():
     for i in range(1,10):
          return i

valuee=value()
clamp(valuee)
```

Comment: Return ends your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `return` you will end the function. You are looking for a generator; just change the `return` for `yield`.

```py
def clamp(valuee):
    print(valuee)

def value():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield i
```

You can use your generator in 2 ways: inside a loop

```py
for valuee in value():
    clamp(valuee)
```

Or as you originally wanted, but you have to add the keyword `next`:

```py
def clamp(valuee):
    print(valuee)

def value():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield i
        
valuee = value()
clamp(next(valuee))
clamp(next(valuee))
clamp(next(valuee))
...
```

Comment: by adding keyword next i get error : TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator

Comment: I modified the answer with the complete code for the next case, could you give it a try now please? It runs on my side (python 3+)

Comment: this is just adding it one by one 'clamp(next(valuee))', i want from 1->10, with one code not 10 code...

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing all the values because in value() method you are using return and when i=1 in loop, value() returns 1 and exits from the function and loop too.
you can use ...
def clamp(valuee):
print(valuee)

def value():
for i in range(1,10):
clamp(i)
value()